# How to change the state correctly? (read-only error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Each click calls the function `handleSubmit`.
In the function I have to increase the page number by 1.
But the console error **Uncaught Error: "page" is read-only**
How to change the state correctly?

```
const Cards = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setPage(page += 1);
    const axios = require('axios');
    const url = '/users'

    axios.get(url, {
      params: { page: page }
    }, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'}})
    .then(function (response) {

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function () {
      // always executed
    });
  };

  return (
    // ...
  )

};

export default Cards;
```

Comment: use `setPage(page + 1)`

Comment: `page` is read-only because you say it is: `const [page (...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `page += 1` use `page + 1`. Your state should be immutable, so you should never use `=` operator when you update your state. You should update it with brand new value each time you do it. This should save you a lot of time during development.

Answer (score 2):

By writing `setPage(page += 1);` you are assigning the value `page+1` to `page`. But `page` is read-only and cannot be modified directly. We need to use the setter `setPage` in below manner:

`setPage(page+1)`

Here we are not assigning anything to page directly, but telling the setter to set the incremented value to `page` instead.

Please try this and let me know if any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a similar example

https://codesandbox.io/s/functional-component-api-calls-qgho3

You can use `page + 1`. Check the above example